# How to change input soap request as per test data in loadrunner?

Tags: web-services, soap, performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am working with one soap request where we need to pass,single data in one parameter and in 2nd iteration we need to pass multiple test data in same input request.Please help me how to change input soap request as per test data,please find below soap requests for single and multiple requests.

Single Request:

```
<ReqDtls>
<vReqs>
  <amount>1.00</amount>
  <cardNo>8897654778999</cardNo>
</Reqs>
<cardType>caredit</cardType>
</ReqDtls>
```

Multiple Requests:In same soap input requests,it is changing dynamically from POS system but i want to perform in loadrunner.

```
<ReqDtls>
<vReqs>
  <amount>1.00</amount>
  <cardNo>8897654778999</cardNo>
</Reqs>
<vReqs>
  <amount>2.00</amount>
  <cardNo>890897654778999</cardNo>
</Reqs>
<cardType>caredit</cardType>
</ReqDtls>
```

Any code in vugen to pass this type of values from excel file for loadtesting,please help how to do this one

Comment: You can run  a pre-request script (can be any file) to generate the SOAP request and store in a global variable in every iteration and then pass that variable to your script.

Comment: Hi Kaustav,Please provide with examples, so that i can understand clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where you will use your foundation skills in programming as well as a web_custom_request() (Potentially) to send your own custom string.

Notice the repeated piece here

```
<vReqs>
  <amount>{amount_variable}</amount>
  <cardNo>{card_variable}</cardNo>
</Reqs>
```

You have a defined header

```
<ReqDtls>
```

And a defined footer

```
<cardType>caredit</cardType>
</ReqDtls>
```

This now becomes a matter of string concatenation in C and turning the variables into literals.  Consider a loop and lowly sprintf() for this task.  Note, variable declarations are not included in the code fragment

```
sprintf(mybigstring,"<ReqDtls>\r");
for (myloopcounter=1;myloopcounter<=mylooplimit;myloopcounter++)
{
     sprintf(mybigstring,
          "%s%s",
          mybigstring,
          lr_eval_string("<vReqs>\r<amount>{amount_variable}</amount>\r<cardNo>{card_variable}</cardNo>\r</Reqs>\r") );
     lr_advance_param("amount_variable");
     lr_advance_param("card_variable");
}
sprintf(mybigstring,"%s%s",mybigstring,"<cardType>caredit</cardType>\r</ReqDtls>");
```

The above is directly from noggin to screen so it may require a bit if fiddling, but it should give you an idea for a path.

Once you have your string, then you can use it in whatever request as needed.